# using tidy evaluation (curly-curly) with purrr

Tags: r, purrr, rlang, tidyeval

How can I iterate over functions that use tidy evaluation (via `rlang`'s curly-curly)?

Here's a basic example, where I attempt to iterate over column names using `purrr::map()`:

```r
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")

myfunc <- function(by) {
  mtcars %>% count({{ by }})
}

# passing unquoted arguments doesn't work
c(cyl, vs, am, gear) %>% map(~ myfunc(by = .x))
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'cyl' not found

# passing quoted arguments also doesn't work
c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear") %>% map(~ myfunc(by = .x))
#> Error in `map()`:
#> ℹ In index: 1.
#> Caused by error in `count()`:
#> ! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
#> ✖ Column `.x` is not found.
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

How to get around this problem?

Comment: This seems to work fine if you don't use the (non-recommended) formula syntax, e.g. `c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear") %>% map(myfunc)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to create a vector of unquoted symbols `c(cyl, vs, am, gear)`, R will try to evaluate this before the next step in the pipeline. None of `cyl`, `vs`, `am` or `gear` exist in the global environment, so this will fail.

If you want to do things this way, you can explicitly tell R that these arguments shouldn't be evaluated until later, which can be done using `rlang::quos()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

myfunc <- function(by) {
  mtcars %>% count({{ by }})
}

# passing unquoted arguments doesn't work
rlang::quos(cyl, vs, am, gear) %>% map(~ myfunc(by = !!.x))
#> [[1]]
#>   cyl  n
#> 1   4 11
#> 2   6  7
#> 3   8 14
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   vs  n
#> 1  0 18
#> 2  1 14
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   am  n
#> 1  0 19
#> 2  1 13
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   gear  n
#> 1    3 15
#> 2    4 12
#> 3    5  5
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that you'll also need to use `!!` for this to work - otherwise R will look for a column called `.x`.

A more idiomatic approach would be to use a character vector and to subset the `.data` pronoun like so:

```r
c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear") %>% 
  map(~ myfunc(by = .data[[.x]]))
```

You could also use `across()` combined with `all_of()`:

```r
c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear") %>% 
  map(~ myfunc(by = across(all_of(.x))))
```

As you can see, there are lots of approaches you can take - this is called *non-standard evaluation (NSE)*, and it's a broad topic. To learn more I'd recommend reading [`vignette("programming", package = "dplyr")`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) and the set of articles on metaprogramming from the [{rlang} documentation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/).

Comment: Many thanks @wurli for your detailed and considered answer. Your first solution (using `rlang::quos`) seems most versatile - it has the added benefit of working with functions that take multiple variables (for example, counting by multiple columns).

Answer (score 1):

This is one alternative to tackle this issue:

```
c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear") %>% map(~ myfunc(by = !!sym(.)))

[[1]]
  cyl  n
1   4 11
2   6  7
3   8 14

[[2]]
  vs  n
1  0 18
2  1 14

[[3]]
  am  n
1  0 19
2  1 13

[[4]]
  gear  n
1    3 15
2    4 12
3    5  5
```

Comment: I think this is exactly equivalent to `by = .`

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```r
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")

myfunc <- function(by) {
  mtcars %>% count(!!ensym(by))
}

c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear") %>% map(myfunc)
#> [[1]]
#>   cyl  n
#> 1   4 11
#> 2   6  7
#> 3   8 14
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   vs  n
#> 1  0 18
#> 2  1 14
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   am  n
#> 1  0 19
#> 2  1 13
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   gear  n
#> 1    3 15
#> 2    4 12
#> 3    5  5
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>